# Partial Apply forwarder in closure during Alamofire > 4.3 call

Tags: ios, swift, closures, alamofire

I have an issue that I really don't understand in Alamofire, probably Swift knowledge missing here.

I don't have any failure in my application, everything runs. It just ignore some closure at some point. Instead of finding my data inside my closure in debugger Xcode show me this :

```
0x0000000106eb1b30 AGKitCore partial apply forwarder for closure #1 
(Alamofire.DataResponse<Swift.String>) -> () in static 
AGKitCore.AGKit.add(document: Foundation.Data, withFileType: 
AGKitCore.AGKit.documentType, withIdentifier: 
Swift.Optional<Swift.String>, completionHandler: (Swift.Optional<Swift.Int>) -> ()) -> ()
```

To add more context AGKit is called statically like this :

````
AGKit.add(document: someData, withFileType: .jpeg, withIdentifier: self.cart_local_id) { statusCode in ...closure } ```
````

and the function :

```
  AGKit.sharedInstance.core.api.upload(multipartFormData: { form in
        form.append(document, withName: "image", fileName: identifierForDocument, mimeType: "")

    }, with: Router.sendDocument(identifier: identifierForDocument)) { (results) in

        switch results { 
        case .success(request: let uploadDocumentRequest, streamingFromDisk: _, streamFileURL: _):
            //Pass here
            uploadDocumentRequest.responseString(completionHandler: { responseString in
                completionHandler(responseString.response!.statusCode) //this is never called
            })

            break

        case .failure(let error): //No failure too
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completionHandler(-1)
            break
        }
    }
```

So how should I manage this use case  of closure ? 
Thanks :D

(N.B : this is working very very well in Alamofire 4.3 and before, it has stopped working from 4.3+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update : 
So the error I was getting came from Alamofire that has a bug in a certain version : when a remote host wasn't responding at all (e.g when Alamofire could not resolve the host) the closure wasn't applied correctly. Instead nothing happen, which lead to this particular problem.